# No Unit in the Convolution Semigroup

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, convolution, fourier-transform

How does one prove the following proposition for convolution $*$?

There is for $p\in[1,\infty)$ there is no $g\in L^p$ such that $f*g=f, \forall f\in L^p$ where $*$ is the convolution.

It will be great if one can show it first for $p=1$ then for $p>1$.

---

I can prove the case for $p=1$ easily. Fourier transforming, denoted by $\hat f$ of a function $f$, the above equation I obtain $\,\hat g=1$, contradicting $\hat f(\xi)\rightarrow 0$ as $|\xi|\rightarrow\infty$ from the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma). So such $g$ does not exist.

One can use Fourier transform for $p\in (1,2]$ if the function satisfies additional regularity conditions. But how does one prove the proposition without addition conditions and for arbitrary $p\in (2,\infty)$ with and without Fourier transform? Would the [Young's inequality for convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Young.27s_inequality_for_convolutions) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a ball of radius $r \in (0,+\infty)$, and $f = \chi_B$ its characteristic function. Since the ball has finite measure, we have $f \in L^1 \cap L^{\infty}$, so in particular $f \in L^p$ and $f \in L^q$, where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. Since $f \in L^q$, the convolution $f \ast g$ is continuous for all $g \in L^p$. But $f$ has no continuous representative, so $f \ast g \neq f$, and $g$ is not a unit for the convolution.

Comment: Aha, using the regularity of the convolution. Thank you, Daniel. A further question: Is there a nonvanishing integrable pair $(f,g)$, allowing, say $f\in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$ where $p$ and $q$ may not satisfy $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$, such that $f*g=f$?

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Avenue:** Prove that if $g > 0$ on a set of non-zero measure, then $g$ fails to be the unit of convolution

Comment: I suppose you switched the role of $f$ and $g$. I meant $g$ to be the unit in question. But that matters little. I do not get the hint though. Suppose $g$ is something close to a Dirac delta function, then the convolution is a smoothed version of $f$ and very close to it. But I do not see how that can lead to a contradiction. Could you please elaborate on the hint just a little bit --- you don't have to provide the whole answer?

Comment: There was a typo there. The point is to construct an $f$ that will be different from its smoothed out version using $g$.

Comment: Given $g$ we are to find such an $f$ that the averaged $h=f*g$ is different from $f$ at not just finite number of points but at enough points of positive measure such that $\|h-f\|_p>0$. I do not know how to proceed. I need more elaboration.

Comment: @Hans not so sure myself, now.  Leaving the answer up as CW in case it ends up being useful